# Magento cron job export / import products

Tags: php, magento, csv, cron

My client has an existing Magento store online. Now, they wanna to setup another store at different region. Of course, they will have different currency, shipping method, payment method, different price and different inventory stock check.

Therefore, they required to replicate the same existing store to another folder. Now my problem is they want to have same product range available from both website. My product list is comprised of simple and configurable products only.

I need to set a cron job to export product lists in csv from website A.

And I need to set another cron job to fetch that csv file from website A to website B. However, the product list to be imported into website B should not

> 1. duplicate same record
> 2. update inventory and price value

My current setup for both website are hosted in same server.

I not sure how this can be done. Anyone can guide me. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Answer (score 0):

why do u want to set-up whole new magento store for second region.
u can use magento's multiple store. for that u don't have to import and export of product. infact u just have to create new magento store and payment methods, currency or whatever u want to change u can change those from configuration very easily, u can use differnt theme for both differnt stores also.

U can use this link as a refrence
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

Comment: the problem is product inventory in magento is global value. therefore, client couldn't identify how many stock available in different region.